# ASP.NET Core NullReferenceException when just accessing model

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having trouble with attempting to create a view with a strongly typed model. No matter what I pass in as the model to a `View()`, I always receive a `NullReferenceException` when even just accessing the `Model`.

I can't even check if the model is null before executing the rest of the razor page; simply doing a `if (Model != null)` also throws the same `NullReferenceException`.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model EncodeModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Encode</h2>

<div id="progress">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Encoder/MVC/EncodeProgress.cshtml", new EncodeModule())
</div>
```

**EncodeProgress.cshtml**

```
@page
@model FFenc.IEncoderModule

@{
    var module = Model; //this throws the NullReferenceException
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Exception stack trace:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> AspNetCore.Encoder_MVC_EncodeProgress.get_Model()
>   AspNetCore.Encoder_MVC_EncodeProgress.ExecuteAsync() in EncodeProgress.cshtml
>   var module = Model;

What am I doing wrong? I have attempted multiple fixes and workarounds (using a ViewComponent instead of a view) but nothing works.

Some similar questions that I have found that have not solved my problem:

[ASP.NET Core Model null error in the Index view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472025/asp-net-core-model-null-error-in-the-index-view)

I'm already passing in the model so this answer doesn't change anything about what I'm doing. For example, when I was trying to use a controller as a workaround, the same `NullReferenceException` happened with this code:

```
    [Route("/encode/progress")]
    public IActionResult GetProgress()
    {
        return View("~/Encoder/MVC/EncodeProgress.cshtml", new EncoderModule());
    }
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think you're mixing [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) with ASP.NET MVC.  Try removing the `@page` directive and your model should be bound to the value passed when you call `return View()`.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. Resharper marks the `Model` variable as undefined without the `@page` directive but I found another question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130521/visual-studio-cannot-resolve-model-but-razor-pages-loads . Thanks again!

Comment: Just a heads up, that other question is unrelated.  ASP.NET Core (which includes MVC & Razor Pages) is a pretty new development framework whereas ASP.NET MVC (*not* Core) has been around for almost a decade.  Razor Pages specifically I think is only about a year old.  If you're new to it all it can be a little confusing.  There's a lot of overlap, but there's also differences.  Core is absolutely the way to go for any new development.  I just wanted to let you know so you get off on the right track.