# MVC 'Model' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a _Layout file that contains this. The _HeaderModel class gets initialized correctly.

```
<partial name="_Header" model='new _HeaderModel((int?)ViewData["ActiveIndex"])' />
```

_Header contains

```
@page
@model Project.Pages.Shared._HeaderModel
@Model.ActiveIndex
```

I get this error:

```
'Model' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
```

Model isn't even a null reference; trying to access the property throws this exception. I really can't do it any more basic. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: This has nothing to do with the generic NullReferenceException thread. I know what a NullReferenceException is (duh) but why would it be happening here? This is a very specific case that regards ASP.NET Core 2.

Comment: Is it ASP.NET Core, right? And are you using controller + view?

Comment: ASP.NET Core 2.2, using plain Razor page. I know what a NullReferenceException is (duh) but why would it happen here?

Comment: Have you tried to specify full name in `partial` to page like `/Page/Shared/_Header`?

Comment: That doesn't change anything, except that I must then add .cshtml at the end

Comment: What is `@Model.ActiveIndex` supposed to be (or do) ?

Comment: Does the HeaderModel constructor set the activeindex or leave it an uninitialized null?

Comment: The constructor sets it; but you never get to read that property because I can't even get a reference to Model. Constructor: public _HeaderModel(int? activeIndex) { this.ActiveIndex = activeIndex; }

Comment: Why did 2 people vote to close the question without having any clue about the answer?

Comment: Oh, found the answer here!! Removing @page at the top of the partial view fixes it https://stackoverflow.com/a/52014029/3960200

Comment: @EtienneCharland PLEASE add your last comment as an answer then Accept it, at least 7 other people agree with me. Thank you btw!

Comment: I cannot post any solution as the question has been closed