# Populate Razor SelectList From Code (No Database)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a simple Razor Page called RobotSsh.cshtml, with a model called RobotSsh.cshtml.cs.

I am trying to populate two dropdowns on page load, LocalWifis and CustomerWifis, but nothing happens.

Here is my Razor page (RobotSsh.cshtml):

```
@model App.Views.Home.RobotSsh

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Supportinator 3000</h1>
<div>
    <select asp-for="LocalWifis" asp-items=@Model.LocalWifis></select>
    <select asp-for="CustomerWifis" asp-items=@Model.CustomerWifis></select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my model (RobotSsh.cshtml.cs):

```
public class RobotSsh : PageModel
{
    public SelectList LocalWifis { set; get; }
    public SelectList CustomerWifis { set; get; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        GetNetworks();
    }
    
    public void GetNetworks()
    {
        List<string> wifiNetworks = ["Local Network", "Customer Network"];
        
        LocalWifis = new SelectList(wifiNetworks, wifiNetworks[0]);
        CustomerWifis = new SelectList(wifiNetworks, wifiNetworks[0]);
    }
}
```

I have removed the @page tag from the razor page as it gave me this problem: [@page problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013771/asp-net-core-nullreferenceexception-when-just-accessing-model)

Answer (score 3):

You can implement the `SelectList` as follows

```
List<string> wifiNetworks = new [] { "Local Network", "Customer Network" };
LocalWifis = wifiNetworks.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
{ 
    Text = x,
    Value = x,
    Selected = x == "Local Network"
});
```

Finally remember to bind your properties.

```
[BindProperty]
public SelectList LocalWifis { get; set; }
```

Or you can optionally decorate them with `ViewData` attribute and access them in the view like `@ViewData["LocalWifis"]` instead.

```
[ViewData]
public SelectList LocalWifis { get; set; }
```

**Update:**

You can implement as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class RobotSshModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public string SelectedLocalWifi { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string SelectedCustomerWifi { get; set; }

    [ViewData]
    public SelectList LocalWifis { set; get; }
    [ViewData]
    public SelectList CustomerWifis { set; get; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        GetNetworks();
    }

    public void GetNetworks()
    {
        List<string> wifiNetworks = new List<string>() { "Local Network", "Customer Network" };
        CustomerWifis = LocalWifis = wifiNetworks.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = x,
            Value = x,
            Selected = x == "Local Network"
        });
    }
}
```

Then in the View call:

```
@page
@model RobotSshModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLocalWifi, Model.LocalWifis)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCustomerWifi, Model.CustomerWifis)
```

Comment: @RazorBlazorMazor see the example I have added above on how to use.

Comment: @RazorBlazorMazor also when binding to any element you need to use the @ directive e.g. asp-for="@Model.SelectedLocalWifi"

Answer (score 0):

I tested your codes using RazorPages project. All you need is a correct model reference. You are using `@model App.Views.Home.RobotSsh`. But for RazorPages you should use `@model RobotSshModel`. The syntax is "IndexModel" for Index.cshtml, "ErrorModel" for Error.csthml...etc. For example:

```
@page
@model WebApplication159.Pages.RobotSshModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

[image]
[image]