# Drop down list is showing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectlistItem instead of actual text value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have a drop down list on my Razor page. I am binding the drop down list with a ViewData. below is the code for my controller where I am getting the data from the database:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    List<DocumentType> docTypes = new List<DocumentType>();
    docTypes = await _documentTypeService.GetDocumentTypes(deptId);

    ViewData["DocumentType"] = new SelectList(docTypes, "Id", "Description");
}
```

This is how I am displaying the drop down list and I am also selecting a value for the drop down based on certain condition.

This is the view markup:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>     
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            string selected = String.Empty;
              
            @foreach (var code in (SelectList)ViewData["DocumentType"])
            {
                 if (code.Text.Contains("This is the test for RCA-500"))
                 {
                       selected = code.Text;
                       break;
                 }
            }
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" style="min-width:150px" id="ddldoc_@item.DocumentId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.DocumentType,selected))" asp-for="@item.DocumentType"></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

This drop down is displaying "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectlistItem" instead of the actual values. Not sure what am I doing wrong.

I tried removing the `@` symbol from asp-items, but then I start getting a compiler error saying ";" is missing.

Comment: See this implementation https://stackoverflow.com/a/77826954/23082833

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide the property name for the text displayed and its value as below.

```
<select class="form-control" style="min-width:150px" id="ddldoc_@item.DocumentId" 
    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.DocumentType, "Value", "Text", selected))" 
    asp-for="@item.DocumentType">
</select>
```

However, I believe the approach above will not programmatically select the correct option as it will bind the value based on `DocumentType`'s value.

You should set the desired selected option to `DocumentType` instead of using the `selected` variable.

```
@foreach (var code in (SelectList)ViewData["DocumentType"])
{
    if (code.Text.Contains("This is the test for RCA-500"))
    {
        item.DocumentType = Convert.ToInt32(code.Value);  // Convert the `Value` to the `DocumentType` type
        break;
    }
}

<tr>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" style="min-width:150px" id="ddldoc_@item.DocumentId" 
            asp-items="@(ViewBag.DocumentType as SelectList)" 
            asp-for="@item.DocumentType">
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Without the `foreach` loop, you can achieve with `First()` from the *System.Linq*.

```
@using System.Linq;  // Place on the top of the page

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    item.DocumentType = Convert.ToInt32(((SelectList)ViewData["DocumentType"]).First(x => x.Text.Contains("This is the test for RCA-500")).Value);

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control" style="min-width:150px" id="ddldoc_@item.DocumentId" 
                asp-items="@(ViewBag.DocumentType as SelectList)" 
                asp-for="@item.DocumentType">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And the above logic can be done in the controller action.